# FileNotFoundException thrown when downloading file from URL

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

So I want to download a file from a permanent URL and then save it locally so I can access it later to write into an SQLite database. I have an `AsynchTask` class that handles this functionality but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` error all the time (see Logcat).

**Download CSV file class**

```
private class CSVFileDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {   
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.cardigan.cc/app/locations.csv");  

                //GET FILE FROM URL AND WRITE TO LOCATIONS.CSV LOCALLY
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(entity != null){
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent());
                    filename = "locations.csv";
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)));
                    int inByte;
                    while((inByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(inByte);
                    bis.close();
                    bos.close();
                }

                else if(entity == null) {
                    System.out.println("NO FILE DOWNLOADED FROM SERVER");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null ;               
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //LOAD CSV FILE
            try {
                file = new FileReader(filename); //CREATE READ FOR LOCATIONS.CSV FILE A.K.A filename
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

And the resulting **LogCat** printout:

```
02-23 00:12:16.550: W/System.err(28119): java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(BufferedReader.java:92)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.BufferedReader.<init>(BufferedReader.java:80)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper.onCreate(MySQLiteHelper.java:90)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper.getAllMapMarkers(MySQLiteHelper.java:199)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.CeredigionTourism.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:40)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5048)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:675)
02-23 00:12:16.610: W/System.err(28119):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:17.180: W/System.err(28119): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/locations.csv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper$CSVFileDownloader.doInBackground(MySQLiteHelper.java:296)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper$CSVFileDownloader.doInBackground(MySQLiteHelper.java:1)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-23 00:12:17.770: W/System.err(28119):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-23 00:12:17.780: W/System.err(28119): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
02-23 00:12:17.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:17.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-23 00:12:17.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
02-23 00:12:17.780: W/System.err(28119):    ... 10 more
02-23 00:12:18.730: W/System.err(28119): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/locations.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper$CSVFileDownloader.onPostExecute(MySQLiteHelper.java:319)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper$CSVFileDownloader.onPostExecute(MySQLiteHelper.java:1)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5048)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:675)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-23 00:12:18.780: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-23 00:12:18.790: W/System.err(28119):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
02-23 00:12:18.790: W/System.err(28119):    ... 16 more
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong? Not sure if the file is even downloading and definitely don't know why it can't be found as a resource?!

Answer (score 0):

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/locations.csv

Its trying to find the file locations.csv in the resources folder of your app. You need to specify the path of sdcard in case you want to store the file on the device.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


// Now you can wrap this outputstream with BufferedOutputStream 
//and copy contents of the file that you are getting from the website
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
int inByte;
while((inByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(inByte);
bis.close();
bos.close();
```

Comment: I don't have an SD Card on my tablet. I want to store the file WITHIN the app itself, because I only want this application to use this file as a resource.

Comment: I have modified it and now `BufferedReader` is been given as a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Refer the code mentioned in "Saving to Internal Storage" section in the following URL : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html